# Topological vector space with separating dual space

Tags: topological-vector-spaces

Let ‎$ X $ ‎‎‎be a topological vector space  with dual  ‎$ X‎^{‎\ast‎}‎ $. Has  ‎$ X $  Hahn-Banach Extension Property, ‎i‎f ‎$ X‎^{‎\ast‎} $‎ ‎‎  separates points of ‎$ X $ ?
(Hahn-Banach Extension Property is that: if whenever ‎$ f $‎ is a continuous linear functional on a subspace ‎$ E $ ‎o‎f ‎$ X $  then ‎$ f $‎ 
has an extension ‎$  F ‎\in  X‎^{‎\ast‎}‎ ‎$ ‎)‎